# Is it possible to recover a deleted file from crontab -r?

Tags: files, cron

I made a very serious mistake. I was editing the `crontab` file of my remote server, I was as the root user and it turns out that I wrote `crontab -r` instead of `crontab -e` and without previous notice it was simply deleted.

I was looking for information and it turns out that files deleted with the `crontab -r` command are not stored somewhere like the recycle bin or something similar. I am very worried because there are scheduled backups and all the scripts that my hosting placed. I already communicate with them and I must wait for a response from a specialized person in a period of 24 to 48 hours, but I am very concerned. Will it be possible to recover that file?

Comment: I did not understand you.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to recover the file unless you have a backup to restore it from.

For the future, I would recommend a sequence of operations like this

```
vi ~/.crontab              # Edit a local file
crontab ~/.crontab         # Set this file as your crontab file
```

If you get into the habit of only ever editing the copy and not the installed version you will always have a get-out in the event that you accidentally corrupt the copy:

```
crontab -l > ~/.crontab    # Create the local file as a copy of your crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to recover a file, please use extundelete tool from link http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You might want to point out that it's really important the `extundelete` tool is not installed onto the partition that held the deleted file.